# How to connect edge in image with missing pixels in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

Let's say I have an image

[image]

For the first image, the edge in the bottom object fails to connect to the object above it. I want it to look like this:

[image]

where the red dots are an example of how newly inserted pixels can connect the edge of the bottom object to the object above it

How can I use Matlab so it can connect the missing pixels in the broken edge?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to first apply a morphological close operation using [`imclose`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html) to fill the gap. Since this will also fill corners and such, which you may not want, you can then use [`bwmorph`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) with the `'skel'` option to shrink the lines to the skeleton, then add this to the original image:

```
% Load and binarize your sample image:
bw = imbinarize(rgb2gray(img));

% Adjust this based on the gap size you want to fill:
radius = 15;

% Pad the edges first to avoid edge effects:
bwPad = padarray(bw, [radius radius], 0, 'both');

% Apply the close and skeleton operations:
bwSkel = bwmorph(imclose(bwPad, strel('disk', radius)), 'skel', Inf);

% Remove the edge padding:
bwSkel = bwSkel((1+radius):(end-radius), (1+radius):(end-radius));

% Combine the original and skeleton images:
bw = bw | bwSkel;
```

This gives you the following image:

[image]

The line is rather thin, so if you wanted something thicker you could dilate the skeleton first before adding it to the original using [`imdilate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html):

```
bw = bw | imdilate(bwSkel, strel('disk', 5));
```

[image]